# Insert data from SQL query into a DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

First of all, I have to say that I am new with C#. What I want to do is** display some information through a DataGridView**. I get a row from an SQL query and want to display this row using DataGridView.

**What is the most efficient way to do this?**
I have a function that gets the values ​​from the sql query and returns it with a string[].Would be better return a DataGridView?

And then, how can I assign this values to the DataGridView? This is what I am trying but doens't work.

```
        string[] x = new string[6];
        DataGridView newdata = new DataGridView();
        x = fbd.consultar_Estado_Etiqueta(etiq);

        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

        row.Cells[1].Value = x[1];
        row.Cells[2].Value = x[2];
        row.Cells[3].Value = x[3];
        row.Cells[4].Value = x[4];
        row.Cells[5].Value = x[5];
        row.Cells[6].Value = x[6];
        dataGridView_infoEtiqueta.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: Did you study the documentation and the many examples there?  The simplest way is to fill a DataTable and use it as a DataSource.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp so, the better way is return a DataTable and bind it with the DataGridView using a DataSource?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do you manage your connection with th database. The simplest way is to use Dataset and define it as Datasource for your grid. Something like this:

```
var select = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE";
var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString); // connection string!
var Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, connection); 
var Builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(Adapter);
var myDataSet = new DataSet();
Adapter.Fill(myDataSet);
dataGridView_infoEtiqueta.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: The **simplest** way doesnt need a DataAdapter, DataSet or CommandBuilder - certainly not temporary local ones.  You dont even need a DataTable but it is often nice to have a persistent respoitory.

Comment: I agree with you but as i said it all depends on how he's managing database connection! the essential thing is to build a datasource for the grid